# Trying to install Git auto-completion on a Mac

Tags: git, macos, autocomplete

I'm taking a Git course and am currently trying to install auto-completion but to no avail, and I'm not the only one on there who's taken an L. My second attempt was to download Git via Brew and follow the instructions from a post. I used the command

`sudo find / -type f -name "git-completion.bash"`

and the script is on my laptop. Now I have to create

`usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/`

and have been unable to do it. Now I'm stuck and cannot move on to the next step. Can anyone shed a light?

This is the link to the post: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-enable-git-tab-completion-bash-mac-os-x-conor-livingston/

P.S. I'm a total newbie here, so sorry for any *faux pas* :/

Comment: Why are you unable to create it?

Comment: It reads on Terminal that `usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/` is a directory. I then pasted:`sudo cp /current/path/to/your/git-completion.bash /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash` and got the message: No such file or directory.

Comment: I also got the file git-completion.bash from Github, moved it to have .git-completion.bash and in .bash_profile added in it `[ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then source ~/.git-completion.bash fi`                                                                                          https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/completion

Comment: You know the path is “/current/path/to/your ...” did you change this?

Comment: It's working now. Thanks!